# firefox add-on use `Components` global lead to tests fails

Tags: firefox, components, jpm

I using JPM build the xpi package for firefox addon, but JPM insert a file bootstrap.js into xpi package automatically. It will lead to test fails when I submit addon to the addon developer hub. Extension tests info as following:

```
    Access to the `Components` global
    Warning: Access to the `Components` property is deprecated for security or other reasons.

    bootstrap.js
    const { utils: Cu } = Components;
    const rootURI = __SCRIPT_URI_SPEC__.replace("bootstrap.js", "");
```